# Invalid Content Length when calling Microsoft Graph API upload endpoint in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rest, microsoft-graph-api

UPDATE: This issue is related to a difference between pwsh 7.1 and 5.1. Script works in 5.1 but not 7.1. Encoding issue perhaps. I've tried setting Content-Type to 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8' but it doesn't matter

I've got a pwsh script that does a few things for our CI pipeline:

1. Creates a session upload endpoint
2. Splits a file into byteArray chunks
3. Uploads each chunk to the upload endpoint

The script works just fine in all of our AppVeyor pipelines, but now I'm trying to run it locally (to test before I add it to Jenkins), and I'm getting an error that I'm not expecting.

Function that uploads the chunks:

```
function UploadFile([string] $accessToken, [string] $sourceFilePath, [string] $uploadUrl, [int] $chunkSize)
{
    $header = @{"Authorization" = "bearer $accessToken"}
            
    $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($sourceFilePath)

    $numberOfChunks = GetNumberOfChunks -chunkSize $chunkSize -bytes $fileStream.Length

    for ($i = 1 ; $i -le $numberOfChunks ; $i++){
   
        $filePos = $fileStream.Position

        if ($i -eq $numberOfChunks){
            $lastChunkSize = $fileStream.Length - $filePos 
                
            [byte[]]$fileChunk = New-Object byte[] $lastChunkSize 

            $bytesRead = $fileStream.Read($fileChunk, 0, $lastChunkSize);
        }
        else {        
            [byte[]]$fileChunk = New-Object byte[] $chunkSize
            $bytesRead = $fileStream.Read($fileChunk, 0, $chunkSize);
        }   

        $header["Content-Length"] = $bytesRead

        $header["Content-Range"] = "bytes $filePos-$($filePos + $bytesRead - 1)/$($fileStream.Length)"
            
        Write-Host "Uploading chunk $i of $numberOfChunks to OneDrive..."
        $uploadResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Method Put -Uri $uploadUrl -Body $fileChunk -SkipHeaderValidation   
    }

    $fileStream.Close
    $fileStream.Dispose

    RETURN $uploadResult
}
```

And here's some debug output that shows the values of the vars and error:

[image: Output and Error Message]

This same method works fine in our AppVeyor projects. I have no idea why it's not working for me locally (Win 10 x64 and PowerShell 7.1). I've tried casting $bytesRead (int) to a string, but it didn't make any difference. Was wondering if maybe it wasn't a math issue, but a type issue for the Content-Length header option. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, turns out that powershell 7 doesn't like me setting the Content-Length manually. Removing that from the header, and just letting Invoke-RestMethod set the Content-Length automatically, fixed the issue. All I'm setting is Content-Range, as before, and I'm now able to upload chunks to OneDrive from our linux Jenkins box.

Comment: Same error here. Remove the Content-Length setting in the request header solves the problem. Thanks for sharing.